# How do i convert this code made for single LEDs to my LED strip on arduino?

Tags: c, arduino, led, arduino-c++

[LED that I am using with fastLED librairy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJA9w.jpg)

So my project is to make a LED fan with rgb strip, and I'v found something pretty similar but i tried during one week to change the code with the fastLED library to like convert it but i request help please.[the similar code but with digitalWrite like in [POV led arduino project](https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-LEDs-fan-POV-APPLAUSE-sign/):

```
// bit shift through the byte and output it to the pin
 for (int j=0; j<charHeight; j++) {
   digitalWrite(LEDpins[j], !!(b & (1 << j)));
```

(I can't do "digitalWrite" with the LED strip )][2](https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-LEDs-fan-POV-APPLAUSE-sign/)

So I was wondering if someone stronger in code may be able to give me some corrections.

I have an arduino nano that enables 7 leds(I would like to write a message on the side of my [prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Mx0.jpg)) to blink to write a message by retinal persistence. 
What I want to do is when I receive a message in the serial (I'v made a bluetooth app that sends me a word ) I want it to be shown on my prototype when he is rotating. So if I want to show a letter  on the side of my prototype I have to write it like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEL1e.png) I've made it manually but it is too long :

```
 // la lettre A :
    leds[24] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[23] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[22] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[21] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[20] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[19] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[18] = CRGB::Black;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(Pause);

    leds[24] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[23] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[22] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[21] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[20] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[19] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[18] = CRGB::Red;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(Pause);

    leds[24] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[23] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[22] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[21] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[20] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[19] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[18] = CRGB::Red;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(Pause);

    leds[24] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[23] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[22] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[21] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[20] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[19] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[18] = CRGB::Red;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(Pause);

    leds[24] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[23] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[22] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[21] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[20] = CRGB::Red;
    leds[19] = CRGB::Black;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(Pause);

    leds[24] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[23] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[22] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[21] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[20] = CRGB::Black;
    leds[19] = CRGB::Black;
    FastLED.show();
    delay(Pause);
```

So technically it works great but i when i send for example "difficulty" i would like to do it with like a function or something like that. (i can see the idea of how it works but for now I am incapable of doing it).

Please help me,

if you want more information you can tell me .

Ivan Barroso

Comment: Well this is exactly why Arduino is such a bad tool. Suddenly you need a library in order to do something as trivial as activating a GPIO pin. And when the library doesn't work, you can't solve the problem. Skip all these trash libs and just do `DDRx = mask;` .. `PORTx = mask;` where x is the port you want and mask is some 1u << pin. Though with the reservation that you might not be able to drive LEDs directly from all pins - you have to read the manual to tell.

Comment: Hi, @Lundin and thank you for the reply . I see what you are talking about, but the main purpose of my question was to avoid single communication with every led because I have 50 of them. A friend is helping me a bit so if I finish my project I will give the results.

Comment: The last two column blocks of `la lettre A` seem malformed.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't get the LEDs to work at all, or that you wonder how to rewrite this in a sensible array form instead?

Comment: @Armali  thanks for the reply but it's only to show a piece of code, it's not malformed.

Comment: @Lundin no i know how to manipulate the LEDs strip with the fastLED library (https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/wiki) , yes my problem is on the arrays but now i have problems because when i take value from the font.h , the letter is appears "distorted" because of the fact that it is a wheel.

Answer (score -1):

> So if I want to show a letter on the side of my prototype I have to write it like that I've made it manually but it is too long

Understandably you don't want to write down each individual letter column sequence by hand. Here's an example program which makes use of a table of character images (similar to a *character ROM*); it demonstrates the output on an ANSI terminal, but you can easily adapt it to your LED strip.

```
/* cc -std=c99 */

// glyphs taken from https://github.com/uffejakobsen/sysvbanner/blob/master/banner.c
char glyphs[7*(0x7F-' '+1)/8][7*8] =
{ // 7 x 7 pixels for each of our displayable characters (8 side by side)
  "         ###  ### ###  # #   ##### ###   #  ##     ###  ",
  "         ###  ### ###  # #  #  #  ## #  #  #  #    ###  ",
  "         ###   #   # ########  #   ### #    ##      #   ",
  "          #            # #   #####    #    ###     #    ",
  "                     #######   #  #  # ####   # #       ",
  "         ###           # #  #  #  # #  # ##    #        ",
  "         ###           # #   ##### #   ### #### #       ",

  "   ##    ##                                            #",
  "  #        #   #   #    #                             # ",
  " #          #   # #     #                            #  ",
  " #          # ### ### #####   ###   #####           #   ",
  " #          #   # #     #     ###           ###    #    ",
  "  #        #   #   #    #      #            ###   #     ",
  "   ##    ##                   #             ###  #      ",

  "  ###     #    #####  ##### #      ####### ##### #######",
  " #   #   ##   #     ##     ##    # #      #     ##    # ",
  "# #   # # #         #      ##    # #      #          #  ",
  "#  #  #   #    #####  ##### ####### ##### ######    #   ",
  "#   # #   #   #            #     #       ##     #  #    ",
  " #   #    #   #      #     #     # #     ##     #  #    ",
  "  ###   ##### ####### #####      #  #####  #####   #    ",

  " #####  #####    #     ###      #           #     ##### ",
  "#     ##     #  # #    ###     #             #   #     #",
  "#     ##     #   #            #     #####     #        #",
  " #####  ######         ###   #                 #     ## ",
  "#     #      #   #     ###    #     #####     #     #   ",
  "#     ##     #  # #     #      #             #          ",
  " #####  #####    #     #        #           #       #   ",

  " #####    #   ######  ##### ###### ############## ##### ",
  "#     #  # #  #     ##     ##     ##      #      #     #",
  "# ### # #   # #     ##      #     ##      #      #      ",
  "# # # ##     ####### #      #     ######  #####  #  ####",
  "# #### ########     ##      #     ##      #      #     #",
  "#     ##     ##     ##     ##     ##      #      #     #",
  " ##### #     #######  ##### ###### ########       ##### ",

  "#     #  ###        ##    # #      #     ##     ########",
  "#     #   #         ##   #  #      ##   ####    ##     #",
  "#     #   #         ##  #   #      # # # ## #   ##     #",
  "#######   #         ####    #      #  #  ##  #  ##     #",
  "#     #   #   #     ##  #   #      #     ##   # ##     #",
  "#     #   #   #     ##   #  #      #     ##    ###     #",
  "#     #  ###   ##### #    # ########     ##     ########",

  "######  ##### ######  ##### ########     ##     ##     #",
  "#     ##     ##     ##     #   #   #     ##     ##  #  #",
  "#     ##     ##     ##         #   #     ##     ##  #  #",
  "###### #     #######  #####    #   #     ##     ##  #  #",
  "#      #   # ##   #        #   #   #     # #   # #  #  #",
  "#      #    # #    # #     #   #   #     #  # #  #  #  #",
  "#       #### ##     # #####    #    #####    #    ## ## ",

  "#     ##     ######## ##### #       #####    #          ",
  " #   #  #   #      #  #      #          #   # #         ",
  "  # #    # #      #   #       #         #  #   #        ",
  "   #      #      #    #        #        #               ",
  "  # #     #     #     #         #       #               ",
  " #   #    #    #      #          #      #               ",
  "#     #   #   ####### #####       # #####        #######",

  "  ###                                                   ",
  "  ###     ##   #####   ####  #####  ###### ######  #### ",
  "   #     #  #  #    # #    # #    # #      #      #    #",
  "    #   #    # #####  #      #    # #####  #####  #     ",
  "        ###### #    # #      #    # #      #      #  ###",
  "        #    # #    # #    # #    # #      #      #    #",
  "        #    # #####   ####  #####  ###### #       #### ",

  "                                                        ",
  " #    #    #        # #    # #      #    # #    #  #### ",
  " #    #    #        # #   #  #      ##  ## ##   # #    #",
  " ######    #        # ####   #      # ## # # #  # #    #",
  " #    #    #        # #  #   #      #    # #  # # #    #",
  " #    #    #   #    # #   #  #      #    # #   ## #    #",
  " #    #    #    ####  #    # ###### #    # #    #  #### ",

  "                                                        ",
  " #####   ####  #####   ####   ##### #    # #    # #    #",
  " #    # #    # #    # #         #   #    # #    # #    #",
  " #    # #    # #    #  ####     #   #    # #    # #    #",
  " #####  #  # # #####       #    #   #    # #    # # ## #",
  " #      #   #  #   #  #    #    #   #    #  #  #  ##  ##",
  " #       ### # #    #  ####     #    ####    ##   #    #",

  "                       ###     #     ###   ##    # # # #",
  " #    #  #   # ###### #        #        # #  #  # # # # ",
  "  #  #    # #      #  #        #        #     ## # # # #",
  "   ##      #      #  ##                 ##        # # # ",
  "   ##      #     #    #        #        #        # # # #",
  "  #  #     #    #     #        #        #         # # # ",
  " #    #    #   ######  ###     #     ###         # # # #"};

#define delay(p)    sleep(1)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char led[25];
void show()
{
    printf("\e[A\e[A\e[A\e[A\e[A\e[A\e[A");
    for (int i = 18; i <= 24; ++i)
        printf("%c\e[B\e[D", led[i] ? '#' : ' ');
    printf("\e[C");
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) return 1;
    char c = *argv[1];
    enum { Black, Red };
    if (c < ' ' || 0x7F < c) return 1;
    int i = c-' ';
    puts("\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    for (int col = 0; col < 7; ++col)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 7; ++row)
            led[18+row] = glyphs[i/8*7+row][i%8*7+col] == ' ' ? Black : Red;
        show();
        delay(Pause);
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i've already the font.h  that works but the letters are not really good looking (the charater images from this site[link](https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-LEDs-fan-POV-APPLAUSE-sign/) )     I will come back here if i finsh this and have trouble. Have a dood day. Ivan Barroso.

Comment: No, allocating some 4.7kb large string mess is not the correct solution to any problem. This was written by someone who doesn't understand ASCII and binary - that is, it was not written by a programmer. They are allocating an 8 times too large table and killing 15% of the AVR flash for no good reason. You need (128 ASCII symbols - 32 non-printables) x width x height / 8 bits. For example 7x7 pixels gives 588 bytes.